# How do I retrieve scenario failure message (cucumber jvm) in the After hook?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have been able to get scenario failure status using scenario.isFailed() but not the error message that gets displayed in the stacktrace.

Comment: Could you provide a code example that show what you are doing?

Comment: @After()
    public void GetScenarioDetails(Scenario scenario)
    {
        Integer passInt = scenario.isFailed() ? 0 : 1;
        String pass = passInt.toString();
        String errMessage = passInt == 0 ? "Test error message" : "N/A";
    }

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the error message that gets returned after a scenario execution

Comment: Why are you trying to retrieve the failure message?

Comment: for error reporting on a dashboard

Comment: One way is to catch the exception in your step code and save the e.getMessage() somewhere, maybe a file, before rethrowing the exception.  Then the After hook could read it from where ever you put it to place in your report.